# Excel VBA Like Function not working

Tags: vba, excel

I use this instruction in `vba`:

```
    str1 = Sheet1.Cells(2, 9)
    str2 = Sheet1.Cells(2, 10)

    cell(2,9)="توابع تبریز"
    cell(2,10)="تبریز"
```

and I write this code:

```
if trim(str1) like "*"+trim(str2) then
msgbox "ok"
end if
```

but this if block not working and Like function return false result.

But when I write this code:

```
a="توابع تبریز " like "*"+"تبریز"
```

but now return True! What happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator is not the problem. Though it is advisable to use `&` instead of `+`

I guess the language is Urdu. If yes then I just remembered it is written from left to right. So in that case try this

```
If str1 Like "*" & str2 Then 'Remove the trim
```

You have to remove the trim as it is trimming the spaces and hence the wild card is not working. See below example.

Example

```
Sub Sample()
    '~~> Trying to imitate Urdu in reverse
    Cells(2, 9) = " aaaa bbbb "
    Cells(2, 10) = " bbbb "

    str1 = Cells(2, 9)
    str2 = Cells(2, 10)

    If str1 Like "*" & str2 Then MsgBox "Hey"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not concatenating strings correctly. Your currently using `+` which is a mathematical operator. Replace your `+` with `&` like so:

```
If Trim(str1) Like "*" & Trim(str2) Then
```

Comment: The `+` operator is not the problem. Though it is advisable to use `&` instead of `+`